# What are the main differences between ArrayList and a CircularArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to build my own `CircularArrayList` without using any of the Java API. But I have surfed through the Internet and can't find the basic difference between and `ArrayList` and a `CircularArrayList`. I always end up with the definition of a Circular Queue.

What is the basic difference between these two data structures?

Comment: What is `CircularArrayList`?

Comment: Why do you want to build it if you don't know what it should do?

Comment: `ArrayList` has a start, index `0` and end, index `size - 1`. Whereas a `CircularArrayList` wraps around. E.g. index `size` is equal to index `0`. The actual index is calculated by `index % size`

Comment: Have a look at this reference: https://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue027.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary differences are:

- A properly implemented<sup>1</sup> an array list has an amortized O(1) append operation, but `O(N)` prepend.
- A circular array list has amortized `O(1)` append and prepend operations.
- An array list has an O(1) operation to remove the last element.
- A circular array list has O(1) operations to remove the first and last elements.

Thus, clearly, the use-cases for circular array lists are for you want to add and remove elements at either end of the list.  This is typically done by mapping the logical list index values modulo the array's current length; e.g.

```
    public E get(int i) {
        // bounds checks ...
        return array[(first + i) mod array.length];
    }
```

Similar calculations are done for other list operations.  Since this makes operations *a bit* slower, you would only use a circular array list in a situation where you *expect* to add and remove from the start as well as the end.

> I always end up with the definition of a Circular Queue.

That's because the ideas are very similar.  A circular array list can be used as a circular queue.  It is effectively a double-ended queue ... a dequeue.

---

<sup>1 - The caveat is that amortized `O(1)` only happens if the list backing array is expanded in proportion to the array size; e.g. the length is doubled.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I don't directly attain the question, but, I provide the code for how to implement the circular array using Java,

```
class CircularArray<T> implements Iterable<T> {


    private T[] items;
    private int head = 0;

    public CircularArray(int size) {    
        items = (T[]) new Object[size];
    }

    private int convert(int index) {

        if (index < 0) {
            index += items.length;
        }

        return (head + index) % items.length;
    }

    public void rotate(int shiftRight) {

        head = convert(shiftRight);
    }

    public T get(int i) {

        if (i < 0 || i >= items.length) {

            throw new java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index " + i + " is out of bounds");
        }

        return items[convert(i)];
    }

    public void set(int i, T item) {
        items[convert(i)] = item;
    }

    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return new CircularArrayIterator<T>(this);
    }


    private class CircularArrayIterator<TI> implements Iterator<TI> {


        private int current = -1;
        private TI[] items;

        public CircularArrayIterator(CircularArray<TI> circularArray) {
            items = circularArray.items;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return current < items.length - 1;
        }

        @Override
        public TI next() {
            current++;
            TI item = (TI) items[convert(current)];
            return item;
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Remove is not supported by CircularArray");
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the task willl be use this circular array data structure to create a customized circular `ArrayList`. However, I am not sure in which circumustances this will help as we won't be able extend the `ArrayList` alike the `Array`.